# Will 'whereis python' always show me the Mac system installed directory rather than the brew installed python directory?

Tags: python, macos

When I do

```
whereis python
```

the output will be

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Will the system python always be displayed with 'whereis' even after installing python via

```
brew install python
```

and editing the bashrc to search in /usr/local first?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it will be the same python that you get when you type just `python` on the command line, it is the python executable that is first encountered when iterating through your $PATH